# Emulating uniq -c in sql

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Given the list ...

```
A
B
A
A
```

... with the desired output ...

```
A 3
B 1
```

One way to do this on the Unix command line is

```
cat list | sort | uniq -c
```

Is there a straightforward way to do it in standard SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the COUNT aggregate function:

```
  SELECT t.column,
         COUNT(*)
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.column
ORDER BY t.column
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can use a group by clause.. 
e,g:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(1)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
```

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_by_(SQL)#Queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_by_%28SQL%29#Queries)

Comment: How did you come up with `COUNT(1)`? I've never seen that before. Usually one uses `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)`, or `COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME)`.

Comment: 1 is a valid expression for COUNT function. I use it because it involves less number of key strokes compared to column_name or * . Also note that when you use column_name, rows with null values for that column are not counted.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  letter_,
  count(*)
from 
  table_
group by
  letter_
order by 
  count(*)
```